# Hibernate Issue of understanding what a method is for

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to solve that [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) and I noticed in the end when running the main class :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hibernate one to many (Annotation)");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("PADINI");
        session.save(stock);

        StockDailyRecord stockDailyRecords = new StockDailyRecord();
        stockDailyRecords.setPriceOpen(new Float("1.2"));
        stockDailyRecords.setPriceClose(new Float("1.1"));
        stockDailyRecords.setPriceChange(new Float("10.0"));
        stockDailyRecords.setVolume(3000000L);
        stockDailyRecords.setDate(new Date());

        stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock);        
        stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);

        session.save(stockDailyRecords);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

in this line,

```
    stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);
```

I couldn't understand what is it useful for ? I tried to remove it, nevertheless it was inserting the rows without any problem, so what is the use of it ? why didn't he use `setDailyRecords(stockDailyRecords)` instead, is there something I am not understanding ?

Comment: its because that Entity class have that object of StockDailyrecords so its setting that data into the other table.

Comment: see this public void setStockDailyRecords(Set<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords) {
  this.stockDailyRecords = stockDailyRecords; } means its creating Set of that object class and if u dont add it then u can not make Set and so it means if u dont add it there will be no prob. but u wont having Set in that case.

Comment: @Krishna aha ok I see, but what about stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords); what does he need it for if session.save(stock); has already been called. how is it affecting the result of session.save(stockDailyRecords);???

Comment: see stock.getStockDailyRecords() its getting that set and add(stockDailyRecords); its adding other object into the Set. stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock); and its seeting stoke data into the other table and as it conneted with Foreign key if m not wrong. and unless and until u dont add have that stock set in that other table u wont be abe to add it in set even

Comment: okey very simple thing is that. try to remove this also and u wont be able to save that StockRecordTable also. stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock); try this.

Comment: If you don't call stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords); the instance of Stock in the Hibernate session will not include the newly saved StockDailyRecord.  If you read the Stock instance from the database in a fresh session (or you use evict or refresh) then you will see the effect of the change.

Comment: @Krishna I understand what you mean, but I have deleted the line         stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);
 and I was still able to save into table

Comment: ya but try for some other record na. not for single record.